# Converting DraftJS class component to Functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, draftjs, react-class-based-component

The following Draftjs code is in class component. The plugins like CreateImage, Focus Plugin, and BlockDndPlugin are being imported from the DraftJS. I would be grateful if somebody can convert the class-based react components into Functional based react components...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { convertFromRaw, EditorState } from 'draft-js';

import Editor, { composeDecorators } from '@draft-js-plugins/editor';

import createImagePlugin from '@draft-js-plugins/image';

import createFocusPlugin from '@draft-js-plugins/focus';

import createBlockDndPlugin from '@draft-js-plugins/drag-n-drop';
import editorStyles from './editorStyles.module.css';

const focusPlugin = createFocusPlugin();
const blockDndPlugin = createBlockDndPlugin();

const decorator = composeDecorators(
  focusPlugin.decorator,
  blockDndPlugin.decorator
);
const imagePlugin = createImagePlugin({ decorator });

const plugins = [blockDndPlugin, focusPlugin, imagePlugin];

/* eslint-disable */
const initialState = {
  entityMap: {
    0: {
      type: 'IMAGE',
      mutability: 'IMMUTABLE',
      data: {
        src: '/images/canada-landscape-small.jpg',
      },
    },
  },
  blocks: [
    {
      key: '9gm3s',
      text:
        'You can have images in your text field which are draggable. Hover over the image press down your mouse button and drag it to another position inside the editor.',
      type: 'unstyled',
      depth: 0,
      inlineStyleRanges: [],
      entityRanges: [],
      data: {},
    },
    {
      key: 'ov7r',
      text: ' ',
      type: 'atomic',
      depth: 0,
      inlineStyleRanges: [],
      entityRanges: [
        {
          offset: 0,
          length: 1,
          key: 0,
        },
      ],
      data: {},
    },
    {
      key: 'e23a8',
      text:
        'You can checkout the alignment tool plugin documentation to see how to build a compatible block plugin …',
      type: 'unstyled',
      depth: 0,
      inlineStyleRanges: [],
      entityRanges: [],
      data: {},
    },
  ],
};
/* eslint-enable */

export default class CustomImageEditor extends Component {
  state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(initialState)),
  };

  onChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState,
    });
  };

  focus = () => {
    this.editor.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={editorStyles.editor} onClick={this.focus}>
          <Editor
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            plugins={plugins}
            ref={(element) => {
              this.editor = element;
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not add extra charecters like `.` to bypass the restriction about you not being able to post your question because of too much code. Instead include more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useState and useRef hooks in FC & Modify your component accordingly..

```
const CustomImageEditor = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
    EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(initialState))
  );
  const editor = useRef();

  const onChange = (editorStates) => {
    setEditorState(editorStates);
  };

  const focus = () => {
    editor.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={editorStyles.editor} onClick={focus}>
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          onChange={onChange}
          plugins={plugins}
          ref={editor}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```